# I want to create a live updating score ticker using google docs and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-docs

Currently, on my website, I have static tickers where the data, from a google docs spreadsheet, will only get pulled in when the page is initially loaded. So I was hoping to make some sort of JS widget where, maybe based on a timed basis, news scores would get pulled in without the page being refreshed. Is this (jQuery-> Google Docs relationship) possible? and if so how could I do this?

Comment: try using Javascript's setInterval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascript from this repository: https://github.com/mikeymckay/google-spreadsheet-javascript

Use setInterval function to pull results from spreadseet on a timed basis. More details on js timed events here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp